# How to keep the original directory of a bat file's shortcut?

Tags: batch-file

I have created a batch file which backs up some save game files before launching the game, this is the script:

```
@echo off
set SaveGameLocation=C:\Games\MK X\Binaries\Retail\3DMGAME\Player\remote\user

:: variables
set drive=%cd%\Backup
set dateNtime="%date:~0,2%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~6,6%_%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%"
set backupcmd=xcopy /s /c /d /e /h /i /r /k /y

echo ### Backing up your Sites directory...
%backupcmd% "%SaveGameLocation%" "%drive%\%dateNtime%"
    
"C:\Games\MK X\Binaries\Retail\MKX.exe"
```

This batch batch file is located in `C:\Save Game Backup\MKX` so I've created a shortcut of this file in the desktop, the problem is the current working directory `%cd%` has changed from the batch file location to the desktop, I know that I can simply change `%cd%` to `C:\Save Game Backup\MKX` but I'm always changing the directory and I want a final solution that keeps the file location of the shortcut as the current directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `%CD%`, *which is the current directory*, but instead usiing `%~dp0` *which is the drive and path (including tailing backslash)*, of the running batch file.

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "ExeLocation=C:\Games\MK X\Binaries\Retail"
Set "SaveGameLocation=%ExeLocation%\3DMGAME\Player\remote\user"
Set "drive=%~dp0Backup"
Set "backupcmd=XCopy /C /D /E /H /I /K /R /Y"

Set "dNow=%DATE%"
Set "tNow=%TIME%"
Set "dateNtime=%dNow:~0,2%-%dNow:~3,2%-%dNow:~6,6%_%tNow:~0,2%-%tNow:~3,2%"

Echo ### Backing up your Sites directory...
%backupcmd% "%SaveGameLocation%" "%drive%\%dateNtime%"

Start /D "%ExeLocation%" MKX.exe
```

Comment: Replacing `%cd%` by `%~dp0` worked in this situation for folders, may it work in case with files?